# Is it possible to enable CTRL + Dragging for markers in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'd like the user to only be able to drag a marker when the CTRL key is held down. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> will probably be problematic, because these keys are used by the browsers to mean various actions. However, I tried the following example, binding the <kbd>M</kbd> key to allow dragging while being pressed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps - Drag Marker while Key is Pressed</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
   });
   var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   var markers = [];
   var i;

   var createKeyHandler = function (type, keycode) {
     return (function (e) {
       var keyPress;

       if (typeof event !== 'undefined') {
         keyPress = event.keyCode;
       }
       else if (e) {
         keyPress = e.which;
       }

       if (keyPress === keycode) {
         for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
           // while key is down, all markers are set to draggable = true
           if (type === 'down') {
             markers[i].setDraggable(true);
           }
           else {
             markers[i].setDraggable(false);
           }
         }
       }

       return false;   // Prevents the default action
     });
   };

   // Add 10 random markers on the map
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       draggable: false,
       position: new google.maps.LatLng( 39.00 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20, 
                                        -77.00 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20)
     }));

     markerBounds.extend(markers[markers.length - 1].getPosition());
   }

   // Adjust the map viewport to fit all the markers
   map.fitBounds(markerBounds);

   // Add event handlers for keydown and keyup
   document.onkeydown = createKeyHandler('down', 77);
   document.onkeyup = createKeyHandler('up', 77);

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Tested in Firefox 3.6 for Mac. Doesn't seem to work very smoothly on Chrome however, but I would be optimistic in making it work with a little effort.